# Possible/Plausible to build a program with multiple languages?

Tags: java, c++, programming-languages, large-data

Is it plausible(and/or practiced) to build a large piece of software, for example Altera Quartus II, using multiple programming languages? Meaning, the menus for the software are coded in c++ and maybe the core functional interface that the user interacts with most is built using java. Is this even possible? If so, what are the drawbacks/benefits of doing so with large pieces of software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible and practiced, however it is advisable that the core of your application is build in a mid-level programming language like **c++** for performance, while the front end part and any utilities and interfaces to the core can be built using some other language like **javascript**.

Take a look at the Mozilla browser which is an example of **c++** core with **javascript** UI.

Your question is about whether it is possible: the answer is it is. However I will try to extend a little bit by saying that your challenge in building an application with **c++** and **java** would be the communication between the two parts of your application. You would need some kind of an intermediate like **xml** in order to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to build applications from multiple languages, for instance, you could have your front end coded in C++, the back end written in Java and you use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) for communication.

Although such an application allows you to exploit the features of each language, it requires developers to have expertise in multiple areas or have multiple developers, each of which can increase the cost of the solution being delivered.

Also, nowadays most compilers tend to optimize the code during compilation, so developers do not try and find micro optimizations which allows them to tweak every aspect of their code, unless they are writing something along the lines of AutoCad or Photoshop, each of which require a relatively high amount of system resources.

Another problem with solutions having multiple languages would be how to make them communicate together (sockets, shared memory segments, pipes, etc) so that would be another layer of complexity.